# Signing executables fails inside Docker container

Tags: windows, docker, certificate, signtool, sn.exe

I am trying to sign `.exe` and `.dll` files inside Gitlab Pipeline with `docker-windows` setup, using docker image:
`mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019`

I try to call these commands:
`> sn.exe -R myfile.exe myKey.snk`
`> signtool.exe sign /v /f myCert.p12 /p myPassword /fd sha256 /tr "http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp" /td sha256 myFile.exe`

When doing it locally on my machine files get succesfully signed:

```
> sn.exe -R myfile.exe myKey.snk
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility  Version 4.0.30319.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Assembly 'myFile.exe' successfully re-signed
> signtool.exe sign /v /f myCert.p12 /p myPassword /fd sha256 /tr "http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp" /td sha256 myFile.exe
The following certificate was selected:
    Issued to: someone
    Issued by: some-private-ca
    Expires:   Fri Aug 28 09:40:11 2020
    SHA1 hash: hash

Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed: myFile.exe

Number of files successfully Signed: 1
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 0
```

However, using Gitlab pipeline both Strong Name Tool (`sn.exe`) and `signtool.exe` fail:

```
> sn.exe -R myfile.exe myKey.snk
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility  Version 4.0.30319.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Failed to re-sign the assembly -- Error code: 80131701
> signtool.exe sign /v /f myCert.p12 /p myPassword /fd sha256 /tr "http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp" /td sha256 myFile.exe
The following certificate was selected:
Done Adding Additional Store
```

I was not find out what error code `80131701` refers to.
In some cases people got the error code on `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80131701)`.

Could this be caused by some certificate missing inside docker image, that is present on my computer?

Comment: Searching for answers I have found [someone else also having problems with signing inside Docker](https://xrstf.de/2018/03/safenet-token-code-signing-gitlab-ci/). However the error messages differ.

Comment: I have tried this by running the same docker container on my machine and it works as expected.

Comment: I have replaced local `sn.exe` with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\sn.exe` and now `sn.exe` part works. `signtool.exe` still does not detect any certificate though.

Comment: I have tried installing certificates from `myCert.p12` certificate chain on Gitlab CI Runner machine... but to no help.

Comment: It seems that the signing only works on machines with Windows installations provided by <some_company>. Gitlab Runner machine is regular Windows Server. While the developer machine able to perform the signing was installed using the proprietary Windows installer from <some_company>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fo fix **sn** comamnd, I've had to replace local `sn.exe` file with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\sn.exe`:

```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\sn.exe -R myfile.exe myKey.snk
```

To fix **signtool** command, it was necessary to import certificate in the docker container:

```
> Set-Content myCert.pfx -Encoding Byte -Value ([System.Convert]::FromBase64String(myCert.p12))
> Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath myCert.pfx -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String myPassword -AsPlainText -Force) -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
> $cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
> $cert.Import(myCert.pfx, myPassword, 'DefaultKeySet')
> Set-AuthenticodeSignature -Cert myCert.pfx -TimeStampServer http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp -FilePath myFile.exe -HashAlgorithm SHA256
```

Comment: Is the sign tool exe available in any of the docker images?